# How to show two horizontal scroll menu bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show two horizontal scroll menu bars for my website. So I searched and found custom horizontal scroll menu with left right arrows.

https://jsfiddle.net/c5grnve6/

It works fine when only one scroll menu in the page. If I use two menus, there is a problem.

01) When click right or left arrows, it's moving both menu arrows.

02) Right arrow not hiding when it's reached to end.

So I tried duplicating this code and used different class names but no luck.

```
if (menuPosition <= paddleMargin) {
    $(leftPaddle).addClass('hidden');
    $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
} else if (menuPosition < menuEndOffset) {
    // show both paddles in the middle
    $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
} else if (menuPosition >= menuEndOffset) {
    $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    $(rightPaddle).addClass('hidden');
```

}

How can I do achieve this?

Comment: in your code your using class to select element which is same for both scroll menus, you can give separate id's to each scroll bars and select the one that you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

01) When click right or left arrows, it's moving both menu arrows. It's happening because you have written:

```
// scroll to left
$(rightPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: menuInvisibleSize}, scrollDuration);
});

// scroll to right
$(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: '0' }, scrollDuration);
});
```

Here `rightPaddle` and `leftPaddle` grabs both of the `rightPaddle`s and `leftPaddle`s and then by `'.menu'` both of the menus are moving. You need to give them seperate ids so that they can be called separably.

Comment: Works fine but the moving to left / right not working smoothly. Test it on jsfiddle you can see it.

Comment: @MarkNsu Your right button is not hiding because your last `else if` condition is not getting `true` when your menu is in the most right position, `menuPosition: 124, menuEndOffset: 680` so the last condition `menuPosition >= menuEndOffset` will never be true. try to `console.log` the values you are using in every condition and change the condition.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
 $(rightPaddle).on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: menuInvisibleSize}, scrollDuration);
    });

    // scroll to right
    $(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.menu').animate( { scrollLeft: '0' }, scrollDuration);
    });
```

OR you can use [ParentsUntil](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_parentsuntil.asp)